# Did GOP senators say these things about Kavanaugh allegations?

Tags: politics, sexual-abuse, media, social-media

I saw the following screenshot [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/lannadelgrey/status/1044746410028134400):

[image: MSNBC screenshot]

The picture shows an MSNBC screen with the header "GOP SENATORS ON KAVANAUGH ALLEGATIONS" with pictures and the following quotes:

- "I'll listen to the lady, but we're going to bring this to a close." Sen. Lindsey Graham (R-SC)
- "I mean I can't imagine the horror of being accused of something like this." Sen. Bob Corker (R-TN)
- "I think this woman, whoever she is, is mixed up." Sen Orrin Hatch (R-UT)
- "We got a little hiccup here with the Kavanaugh nomination, we'll get through this and we'll get off to the races." Sen. Dean Heller (R-NSV)

Are these quotes accurate?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Yes**, these appear to be accurate quotes.

---

1. **Lindsay Graham**, from the Washington Post: [Woman who accused Brett Kavanaugh of sexual assault wants FBI to investigate incident before she testifies to Senate](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/grassley-says-mondays-hearing-will-be-limited-to-two-witnesses-kavanaugh-and-his-accuser/2018/09/18/301da074-bb48-11e8-a8aa-860695e7f3fc_story.html?noredirect=on&utm_term=.0256ed1194b8):

> “All I can say is that we’re bringing this to a close,” said Sen. Lindsey O. Graham (R-S.C.). “They’ve had tons of time to do this. This has been a drive-by shooting when it comes to Kavanaugh. . . . I’ll listen to the lady, but we’re going to bring this to a close.”

2. **Bob Corker**, from [ABC's John Parkinson on twitter](https://twitter.com/jparkabc/status/1041805015621492738?lang=en):

> .@SenBobCorker tells me he does not have any outstanding questions for Judge Brett Kavanaugh: "I’ve been impressed with all that I’ve heard about him and again it’s unfortunate. I mean I can’t imagine the horror of being accused of something like this."

3. **Orrin Hatch**, in the Atlantic: [The GOP Response to the Kavanaugh Allegations Sends an Unmistakable Message to Women](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2018/09/brett-kavanaugh-christine-blasey-ford-hearing/570625/):

> After Christine Blasey Ford, a clinical-psychology professor, put her name to the accusation, announcing publicly that she’d passed a polygraph and had shared her story in a 2012 therapy session, Senator Orrin Hatch, a longtime member of the Senate Judiciary Committee’s all-male Republican contingent, told the cameras: “This woman, whoever she is, is mixed up.” He also said that even if the assault accusation were true, the past wouldn’t matter so much: “It would be hard for senators not to consider who he is today.”

4. **Dean Heller**, in the Washington Post: [Two GOP lawmakers criticized for tone-deaf comments about Kavanaugh accuser](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/sen-heller-reportedly-refers-to-kavanaugh-assault-allegation-as-a-hiccup/2018/09/20/06458182-bcbe-11e8-8792-78719177250f_story.html?utm_term=.cdb196a4f5b3)

> “I’m really grateful for the White House, for the effort of President Trump and what he has done, and the excitement that we have,” Heller reportedly said. “We got a little hiccup here with the Kavanaugh nomination. We’ll get through this and we’ll get off to the races.”

Answer (score 8):

The image is really from MSNBC.

Specifically, it's from the [The 11th Hour with Brian Williams 9/20/2018](https://youtu.be/kebj7yXdaaA?t=37m53s) (at 11:47 ET, as can be seen in the image). You can also read the transcript [here](http://www.msnbc.com/transcripts/11th-hour-with-brian-williams/2018-09-20) on MSNBC's website:

> Eugene, I want to read you some quotes that are present day members of the Senate about Dr. Ford. Senator Graham, “I'll listen to the lady, but we're going to bring this to a close.” Senator corker, “I mean, I can't imagine  the horror of being accused of something like this.” Senator Hatch, “I think this woman, whoever she is mixed up.” Senator Heller, “We got a little hiccough here with the Kavanaugh nomination. We'll get through this and get off to the races.”